# Why flexDirection does not change to 'row' in tabBarComponent?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Trying to customize the tabBar of react navigation. I have created a component named as 'tabComponent' and it is call in tabNavigator. I am getting the custom tab as text but they are comming in a single column below one another. But I want them to come in a single row. Below is my tabComponent file.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, Text, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation';

class tabComponent extends Component{
    navigateToScreen = ( route ) => () => {
        const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName: route
        });
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <ScrollView style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                        <Text 
                            onPress={this.navigateToScreen('Home')}
                        >
                            Home
                        </Text>
                        <Text onPress={this.navigateToScreen('Search')}>Search</Text>
                        <Text onPress={this.navigateToScreen('Notifications')}>Notifications</Text>
                        <Text onPress={this.navigateToScreen('Message')}>Message</Text>
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default tabComponent;
```

How to get there tab as Text in a single row **just like the default tabs** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ScrollView` has a prop named `horizontal` taking a boolean value to set the direction :

```
<ScrollView horizontal>
    ...
</ScrollView>
```